# Why accessing a class instance member gives an EXC_BAD_ACCESS? (Xcode beta 5)

Tags: class, swift

I have those classes:

```
class Poi {
    var id: String
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    init () {
       id = ""
       location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0)
    }
}

class CustomMapPinAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var poi: Poi!
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    init(poi: Poi) {
        self.poi = poi
        self.coordinate = poi.location
    }
}
```

Anytime I access to any poi members from an instance of CustomMapPinAnnotation (ie. interpoling a annotation.poi.id in a string for instance) from outside the class CustomMapPinAnnotation, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS despite poi is not nil.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
   println("Pin button Clicked")
    let annotation:CustomMapPinAnnotation = view.annotation as CustomMapPinAnnotation

    let message = "Situé sis \(annotation.subtitle)\nid : \(annotation.poi.id)"     // I have the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code 2) here
}
```

Any idea?

[EDIT1] Debug information where one sees the annotation.poi is well defined.

[image]

[EDIT2] EXC_BAD_ACCESS while printing the name.
[image]

Comment: I think you're missing some code in your example.  Your `Poi` class doesn't appear to have a `location` property

Comment: Yep, I took an excerpt from the whole class. I added the location member though in order not to puzzle readers @sapi

Comment: I don't see where an instance of `Poi` is created.

Comment: When CustomMapPinAnnotation instance is created, a poi instance is store in the self.poi member. Then, later on, in the calloutAccessoryControlTapped, when an access is performed to the annotation.poi.id member, I've got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. @Zaph

Comment: I still don't see where an instance is being created. Also your example is so so intertwined with `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, `MKMapView!` and `MKAnnotationView`  testing is very involved.

Comment: I still don't see where an instance is being created, is the `POI` init called? Also your example is so so intertwined with `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, `MKMapView!` and `MKAnnotationView`  testing is very involved.

Comment: When the delegate method is called, are you sure the annotation is of type CustomMapPinAnnotation?  Try doing `println("Pin button Clicked, type = \(view.annotation.self)")` and see what it says.

Comment: @Anna I added 2 screenshots of the debug information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost such a long time on this, I think —it worths an answer  if someone faces the same "unbelievable" behavior form Xcode.

In a desperate attempt, I simply moved the member on a line below (switching 2 members) and the app runs, no more EXC_BAD_ACCESS! Working code is ass follows now:

```
class CustomMapPinAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var poi: Poi!

    init(poi: Poi) {
        self.poi = poi
        self.coordinate = poi.location
    }
}
```

This behavior is most likely to be attributed to kinda Xcode/compiler bug (Xcode 6 beta 5).

Hope it helps.